# Apple Keyboard with Numeric Keypad on Windows-7

Tags: keyboard, windows

I am using Apple Keyboard with Numeric Keypad on Windows 7 and its numeric pad is not working on windows 7, it was working OK on windows XP, what I can do to make it work on it too?

Comment: This isn't really an Apple question. Any fix will done through the Windows OS. I suggest a migration to Super User.

Comment: Yes, good for press the "clear" key for Operate the Numberic Keypad, but can use after the Computer start-up only. After I try to Open the another Apps cannot operate the "Clear" key anymore. How can I set-up ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hah! I actually use a mac keyboard as the normal keyboard on my windows boxes. I like the laptop-feel and the aluminium.

This is easy to fix.

Push "Clear".

The "Clear" key on the numberpad gets mapped to the "NumLock" key on windows.

If you want to fix the swapping of the alt and "Command" keys, [KeyTweak](http://majorgeeks.com/KeyTweak_d4161.html) works well.
It can also let you set the additional F-keys (e.g. F13-F19, which are not real F-keys) to be  whatever you want. I have them mapped as media keys (next-track, pause, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold "clear" key for three seconds. It will work as NUMLOCK in windows. You can shift to numerics and the "<-- -->" kind of finctions.
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to figure out the "Clear" key (which acts as NumLock on long-press, in Windows) is the square with the "x" inside, on the upper left corner of the numpad, on my Apple keyboard.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  How is this answer any different than the answers already provided?  Your answer just restates the same info.  Please see [answer] for important info on answering questions on this site.